# Was Talbot and Qovas's plan reasonable?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

As mentioned in the show,

> Talbot's

goal of gaining a great deal of power was, at least nominally, motivated by a desire to stop Thanos:

> QOVAS: Thanos and his forces have begun an assault on your world, even as
> we speak.
>
> TALBOT: Well, then, I've got to get down there with the Avengers and take on
> this Thanos.
>
> QOVAS: Thanos' strength is unrivaled. You will lose even with your powerful
> friends fighting alongside you. Though perhaps there might still be a
> way.
>
> <sub>*Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D*, "The One Who Will Save Us All"</sub>

He didn't succeed in getting all of the gravitonium, of course, but that was his goal.

Talbot had a dramatically inflated notion of his own powers, so he can't be trusted, but Qovas was very familiar with gravitonium and Thanos, enough to know that Talbot *without* the additional gravitonium stood no chance (and, really, didn't have any reason to want to make such an unstable individual *more* powerful unless it would benefit him in some way). And in the MCU, even Thanos with all the stones isn't unstoppable, as we saw

> with Thor, and to some extent with Wanda.

So, was this a realistic plan, or was Qovas mistaken or being deceptive? Would all the gravitonium have given Talbot a chance against Thanos? **In particular, has anyone associated with the show commented on this?**

Comment: It is highly unlikely that anyone with the show and/or movies would comment as both are playing off scripts with set destinies and no chance of cross-over.